# Captcha required youtube api C#

Tags: authentication, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

Every time I make a request for getting a video to youtube API I make something like that:

```
public Video GetVideo(string videoId)
{
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

    Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId);

    return request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
}
```

Sometimes I get an exception saying "Captcha required". I was wondering if building the YoutubeRequest is asking for an authentication token for every call to GetVideo and because of that I'm getting this exception. Is it possible? How can I avoid this exception? And I'm not talking about handling it with a try-catch.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; there are ways of reusing a ClientLogin token. Please see scenario 4 in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html), and take a look at the "Recalling an auth token" section of [this document](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin#RecallAuthToken).

Better yet, I'd recommend making the move to OAuth 2 instead of ClientLogin, as mentioned in that blog post.

Comment: Right now I'm doing something like this (caching the token):

request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
string token = Environment.Cache.Lookup<string>("YoutubeToken-" + user);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
 token = request.Service.QueryClientLoginToken();
 Environment.Cache.AddOrUpdateObject("YoutubeToken-" + user, token);
}
request.Service.SetAuthenticationToken(token);

Do you think it would be enough?? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, that seems about right, but you've presumably been able to run that code and verify that it reuses the cached token, right?

Comment: Yes of course and even debugged it, but I was not very sure about it. Thanks a lot Jeff!